# Identify 3rd smallest item in a list with criteria that include a partial string match

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two tables:
1. Table 1 has a list of vacancies with a unique ID (e.g. "284628")
2. Table 2 has a list of candidates including various time stamps (screened, interviewed, etc.). Each candidate entry also has a field for the vacancy field from table1. However, sometimes this field includes multiple vacancy IDs (e.g. "485923; 139042"). There are many candidate rows with the same vacancy IDs.

I want to pull the 3rd smallest time stamp from the column 'Interviewed' in Table2 into Table1 for the corresponding vacancy ID.

How do I create that formula?

I have two pieces of the puzzle, but don't know how they can work together.

Partial match in a string:

```
    =INDEX($B$2:$B$9999,MATCH("*"&D2&"*",""&$A$2:$A$9999,0))
```

3rd smalles value:

```
    {=IFERROR(SMALL(IF(Table2[ID]=[@[ID]];IF(Table2[Date]="";"";Table2[Date]));3);"")}
```

Thanks a lot for anyone helps - I think this is brain teaser :)

As requested, sample data can be downloaded here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11rtyR4eKOok_M4zDi45_D_NvhhRnzBvT9MYZp-WOMKw/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Could you edit your question by adding example data tables (Table 2 in particular)? That would help clarify things. Table 1 for example might be `|   ID   |  DATE  |` but you would also want to include rows showing example data.

Comment: Thanks @xidgel! I just added a link to the sample tables in Google Drive - didn't find an easier way. Hope this helps you help me :)

Answer (score 0):

This may be what you're looking for:

```
=SMALL(IF(ISERR(FIND([@ID],Table2[ID],1)),999999,Table2[Date]),3)
```

entered as an array formula [`CTRL-SHIFT-ENTER`].

**Explanation**

`FIND([@ID],Table2[ID],1)` looks for an `ID` from `Table1` in the `ID`column of `Table2`. This `FIND` returns an `Integer` if it succeeds and `#VALUE` if it fails. Since it's an array formula we get an array of either `Integer` or `#VALUE`, one value for each row in `Table2`.

We wrap the above in an `ISERR(above)`, which gives an array of values that are either `TRUE` (if `ID` was **NOT** found) or `FALSE` (if `ID` was found).

That all gets wrapped by an `IF(above,999999,Table2[Date])`: if `TRUE` we return `999999` (any number bigger than your maximum date); if `FALSE` we return the `Date` from `Table2`. Again we get an array of values.

Finally, wrap the preceding result in `SMALL(above,3)` to return the 3rd smallest from the array.

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks so much for your support! Unfortunately, this didn't work.
I stripped down the formula step by step and it looks like the FIND formula is the issue, as I always get a #VALUE error when I run it. Any idea why? Did it work for you with the sample data?

Comment: It worked for me on the sample data. Did you do CTRL-SHIFT-ENTER when you entered the formula?

Comment: It worked! I noticed a key difference in my sample data and my actual data. In my actual data, I had blank spaces. Changed the web query to fill them with a random date (888888) and it worked!